# How do I get this code for python.display to python.display Iframe on repl?

Tags: python, video

Repl keeps giving me this:

> /home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py:701:
>   UserWarning: Consider using IPython.display.IFrame instead
>   warnings.warn("Consider using IPython.display.IFrame instead")

How does one fix that

```
from IPython.display import HTML

# Youtube
HTML('<iframe width="760" height="515" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7EqhK3L1Yio?autoplay=1-1 rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>') #
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use IFrame instead of HTML. For example:

```py
from IPython.display import IFrame

IFrame(src='src', width='width', height='height')
```